# How to incorporate continuous covariates into the nodematch() function in the ERGM package in R?

Tags: r, igraph

In the `ergm` package, `nodematch` allows us to specify homophily. However, I noticed that it only allows dyadic, character vectors. Is there a way to incorporate continuous variables such as income into the `ergm` function?

The following was taken from the vignette:

```
library(ergm)
data(flo)
flomarriage <- network(flo,directed=FALSE)
wealth=c(10,36,27,146,55,44,20,8,42,103,48,49,10,48,32,3)
flomarriage %v% "wealth" <- wealth
data(florentine)
#
# Fit a model where the propensity to form ties between
# families depends on the absolute difference in wealth
#
gest <- ergm(flomarriage ~ edges + absdiff("wealth"))
summary(gest)
```

It seems that the above handles a continuous variable, but using the absolute difference. Is ergm not able to handle continuous variables?

Comment: Homophily is a measure of similarity between two nodes, so it must be either a binary (same, different) or a single difference variable that is assigned to that edge. Do you mean to add in wealth as a nodal covariate instead? That can be done for example with `ergm(flomarriage~edges+nodecov('wealth')) `

Comment: I forgot to mention I actually have another variable, `gender`, I would like to put in. I would like to simulate a network ultimately that has homophily from both `wealth` and `gender`, with an adjacency matrix being the output.  In that case, would using ergm(flomarriage~edges+nodematch('gender')+absdiff('wealth')) be valid? thanks!

Comment: Yes, in general that's a valid formula for an ergm